# how can vb.net make inherit class with selected variable from base calss

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, inheritance, abstract-base-class

I need to make an inherited class from a base class with a selected variable.
for example,
if the base class have 3 variable name, age, marks
but inherit class must have name and marks only

how can we do it

Comment: You can't really. Any members that are not private will be inherited. Why would you want this? It would break polymorphism, which is one of the main points of inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When designing object-oriented code, subclasses should be the specializations. The situation you describe makes the base class the specialization because it has more specific requirements than the subclass.

There is a principle called the "Liskov Substitution Principle" that says all subclasses should work where the base class works - and this wouldn't be the case as calling `subclass.age` would fail.

Instead, the base class should have the two common properties, and there should be a subclass that represents the extended class that represents the situation where an age would be used.

Score

- Name
- Marks

AgedScore extends Score

- Age

The names are examples here, ideally you'd name them after what they relate to in the business domain.